# Problems installing R packages-C compilers on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: r, compiler-errors, install.packages, anaconda3

I am having issues installing R packages in a conda environment on MacOS 10.15.4. The command `install.packages()` in R leads to the following type of errors (I am not pasting the full log):

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xml2’
```

```
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/k6/p2cdz1dx32g3p4hmwghns3fc0000gn/T/RtmpdPz2VA/R.INSTALL4817a82715f/uuid':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I am using r version 3.6.1 on a platform x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
The clang version is:

clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: /opt/anaconda3/envs/r_omics/bin

So I assumed there was an issue/conflict with the way the C compilers on my computer process R-packages installation but I don't know how to solve this.
Somehow I manage to install some of the packages through `conda install` but I don't manage through this to recover the environment I need.

Thank you very much for your help